# Code help, how to remove / skip an item in a list?

Tags: python

I have a program that reads a txt file with names "surname, first name, Y". one of the names does not have a "Y" and i want to change the code, instead of saying "did not attend any days" to ignore / remove if from the list and not print anything in the output.

```
from time import strftime # import time
print("Report date: " + strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) #Prints clock time

with open("confPack.txt", "r") as confPack: # open file as confpack
    cPack = confPack.read().splitlines() # create cpak variable

with open("employees.txt") as fp: #open file as fp
    for line in fp:
        Name = line.strip().split(",") # iterate through employees, strip, split and list
        surname = Name[0]
        firstName = Name[1]
        # is the last value not a Y (meaning no Y's)
        if Name[-1] != 'Y':
            packs = 'did not attend any days'
        # if that's false, meaning there is a Y, is the one before it a Y too
        elif Name[-2] == 'Y':
            packs = (cPack[1]) # they get bonus pack
        # if the first 2 conditions are not met
        else:
            packs = (cPack[0]) #they get conference pack
        print(f"Attendee: {surname}, {firstName}: {packs}") #print surname, first name and pack using f-string
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `continue` to skip the iteration in the loop. Welcome to SO!

Comment: don't start variable names with a capital: `Name`

Comment: If you want to skip something in a for or while loop, use `continue`

Answer (score 1):

This is what **ggorlen** means:

```
from time import strftime # import time
print("Report date: " + strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) #Prints clock time

with open("confPack.txt", "r") as confPack: # open file as confpack
    cPack = confPack.read().splitlines() # create cpak variable

with open("employees.txt") as fp: #open file as fp
    for line in fp:
        Name = line.strip().split(",") # iterate through employees, strip, split and list
        surname = Name[0]
        firstName = Name[1]
        # is the last value not a Y (meaning no Y's)
        if Name[-1] != 'Y':
            continue
        # if that's false, meaning there is a Y, is the one before it a Y too
        elif Name[-2] == 'Y':
            packs = (cPack[1]) # they get bonus pack
        # if the first 2 conditions are not met
        else:
            packs = (cPack[0]) #they get conference pack
        print(f"Attendee: {surname}, {firstName}: {packs}") #print surname, first name and pack using f-string
```

Answer (score 0):

@ggorlen is definitely right. You can use `try-except` block inside the for-loop.

```
for line in fp:
    try:
        {code}
    except:
        continue
```

Even if you have an error, the loop will continue with the next iteration.